# Ag grid row selection loses after refresh the page

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ag-grid

I'm using ag-grid in Angular 7.x. Whenever the page is refreshed it loses the highlighted row focus. This seems to be a bug in ag-grid.

Is there any workaround, like setting the last selected row focus back to the grid using params ID.

Before page refresh
[image]

After Page refresh
[image]

Comment: You gotta store the state in localStorage (on the browser) or some database (server-side)

Comment: I have stored in localstorage but how to apply to the grid.

Comment: if you share minimal stackblitz, i can give it try...

Comment: One thing you can do, rather than keeping track of the selected rows and the re-selecting them yourself, is tell the grid what is the ID of each row, and it should do it automatically: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-ids/#application-assigned-ids

Answer (score 3):

You need to store your selected rows in the localStorage:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (event) => {
  localStorage.setItem("selectedRows", JSON.stringify(this.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows()));
};
```

and then after the refresh and after you have set your data in the grid, programatically re-select your rows:

```
reSelect = (): void => {
  const selectedRows = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedRows"));

  this.gridOptions.api.forEachNode((node: RowNode, index: number) => {
     // adapt with you own unique role-id rule
     const selectNode = selectedRows.some((row) => { return row.id === node.data.id; });

     if (selectNode) {
        node.setSelected(true, false);
     }
   });
};
```

Comment: how do you know the render was finished?

Comment: @QuethzelDiaz You can use these events to see when render is finished: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111708/how-to-fire-an-event-when-ag-grid-in-angular-is-loaded