# How to fire an event when ag-grid in Angular is loaded?

Tags: angular, events, rxjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Ag-grid in Angular uses showLoadingOverlay() function to show loading bar on grid. How do I know that my angular ag-grid has finished loading?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `gridReady` should fire when the data has been set if using
> `gridOptions.rowData`. If you're using `api.setRowData` you'll need to use
> `rowDataChanged` instead

[Source](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/1602)

If you can post example of how data is assigned to the grid, might be able to offer a better solution.

Comment: rowDataChanged has been changed to RowDataUpdated